# Scrapy crawling fails if too many spiders are used (Crawled 0 pages)

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl prices from a popular reselling platform. For every item, I instantiate the same spider with different searching tags. With less than about 300 items the process works perfectly fine, just not for more than that.
Every spider writes its results to a document before it closes, so there are no special pipelines or yielding hierarchies.

I tried different approaches like

```py
    for c in collection:
        for item in c.get_items():
            crawler = Pricecrawler(c.collection_id, item.id, item.name)
            print(crawler)
            process.crawl(crawler, collection_id=c.collection_id, item_id=item.id, search=(item.name))
    process.start()
```

Or

```py
    runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
    d = []
    for c in collection:
        for item in c.get_items():
            crawler = Pricecrawler(c.collection_id, item.id, item.name)
            print(crawler)
            runner.crawl(crawler, collection_id=c.collection_id, item_id=item.id, search=(""+item.name))
            d = runner.join()
            d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()
```

(Those two work fine for lower numbers of spiders, another try with subprocesses issuing scrapy command line commands did not work).

I tried different settings and addons **in different combinations and with different values** for the past two weeks without any noticeable change to the outcome. (Although I have certainly not tried every possible combination) 
settings and addons like

```py
#settings.set('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)')
#settings.set('TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED', 'False')
#settings.set('TELNETCONSOLE_PORT', None)
#settings.set('CONCURRENT_REQUESTS', 8)
#settings.set('DEPTH_PRIORITY', 8)
#settings.set('DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT', 360)
#settings.set('REACTOR_THREADPOOL_MAXSIZE', 20)
#settings.set('COOKIES_ENABLED', False)
#settings.set('DOWNLOAD_DELAY', 2)
#settings.set('DEPTH_LIMIT', 10)
#settings.set('DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES', {'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
#                                        'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400})

#settings.set('PROXY_POOL_ENABLED', True)
#settings.set('DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES', {'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.ProxyPoolMiddleware': 610,
#               'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620})

#settings.set('CONCURRENT_REQUESTS', 100)
#settings.set('CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN', 100)
#settings.set('DEPTH_PRIORITY', 1)
#settings.set('DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT', 360)
```

And so on...

The spiders get instantiated like this:

```py
    for c in collection:
        for item in c.get_items():
            crawler = Pricecrawler(c.collection_id, item.id, item.name)
            print(crawler)
            process.crawl(crawler, collection_id=c.collection_id, item_id=item.id, search=(item.name))
    process.start()
```

Since the crawler itself is working, when issued from command line or when collections only contain about 300 items, I don't think, there should be a problem.
The params above are put together to form the searching tags.

The outcome with more than ~300 items results in some minutes of

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

Thank you for your time in advance.

Not to forget: I am open for new approaches on how to run multiple instances of one spider with different params, even if it needs much more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `CrawlerRunner.crawl` method's first argument is not an instance of `Crawler`, but a class.

Try to pass it like this:

```py
process.crawl(
    Pricecrawler, 
    collection_id=c.collection_id, 
    item_id=item.id, 
    search=item.name
)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! You are absolutely right. Sadly, fixing this issue did not fix the main problem. However setting up a new scrapy project with [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) on Linux (while the not working version was set up on Windows) fixed it. The code except the part you corrected, is still same.